# Failed to resolve: com.paytm.easypay:easypay:8.5.0-RC-2

Tags: android, payment, paytm

I am trying to integrate Paytm assist for assisting my users with payments. I am following the official site of Paytm for integrating: https://developer.paytm.com/docs/assist/

The problem is the dependency they have given in their official documentation is not resolving. When I add the following to the app module-level build.gradle :

```
implementation 'com.paytm.easypay:easypay:8.5.0-RC-2'
```

It gives the following error:

```
Failed to resolve: com.paytm.easypay:easypay:8.5.0-RC-2
```

Can someone pls help me with the correct version needed or why this error might be coming if the version is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add below maven URL in your repositories section

maven{
url “https://artifactory.paytm.in/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/paytm/easypay/easypay/”
}